# calculating values after rendering page in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate a report which has multiple columns.. After rendering the report I allow the user to enter a value which is to be subtracted from the column which is already rendered.. I have multiple rows.. so I have tries like the following. My views page is

```
<script>
  function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
   if(!isNaN(result))  {
   document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;  } }
</script>
<% @arr.each do |j| %>
<% @q =[] %>
<% t= 0 %>
<%= form_for ProductionReport.new ,:url=>{:controller=>"users",:action=>"rate_per_unit_report" } do |i| %>
<tr>
<td><%= j[0] %></td>
<td><%= j[1] %></td>
<td><%= j[2] %></td>
<% @q << j[3] %>
<td><%= i.text_field j[3], :value=>@q[t], :id=>"txt1", :onkeyup=>"sum()", :class=>"txt" %></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :selling_price, :id=>"txt2", :onkeyup=>"sum()", :class=>"txt" %></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :profit_loss, :id=>"txt3", :class=>"txt", :readonly =>true %></td>
<% end %>
<% t = t+1 %>
<% end %>
<td>total</td>
<td><%= @total %></td>
<td><%= @total1 %></td>
<td><%= @total2 %></td>
```

My controller is

```
def rate_per_unit_report
  @user=User.new
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id]).name
  @rpus = params[:production_report][:intial_date]
  @rpue = params[:production_report][:final_date]
  @production_report = ProductionReport.where(:date => @rpus..@rpue)
  @production = @production_report.select(:finished_goods_name).uniq
  @arr=[]
  g = 0
  @production.each do|i|
    @p = @production_report.pluck(:issue_id)
    @ll = @production_report.where(:finished_goods_name=>i.finished_goods_name).select(:total_no_of_items_produced).sum :total_no_of_items_produced
    @k = Issue.where(:id=>@p).pluck(:consolidated_cost)
    @rate = @k[g].to_f / @ll.to_f
    @r = @rate.round(2)
    @arr<<[i.finished_goods_name]+[@ll]+ [@k[g]] + [@r]
    g = g+1
  end
  @total=@arr.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x[1].to_i }
  @total1=@arr.inject(0){|sum,y| sum + y[2].to_i }
  @total2=@arr.inject(0){|sum,z| sum + z[3].to_i }
end
```

And my sample output page is,
[[image: [1]]]

I want to subtract 5th  column from the fourth column, how could I achieve that.

Kindly please tell me if the information provided is not sufficient.. 
Thank you.

Comment: So you need to dynamically compute profit/loss based on the selling price entered by the user. Is that correct?

Comment: yes Jerry.. Thank you for the quick reply.. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Create Javascript 'objects' that represent each row. Watch for certain events in the 5th column - `onchange`, `onkeyup`, or whichever is suitable. In the event listener, extract the values from the 4th and 5th columns and perform the computation. The key part here is representing each row as a different object with its own set of functions and event handlers.

What'll make achieving this easier is to move the row into a partial and have a script tag that initialises this object there for each row.

Here's a sample that you can use to start with. I'm assuming you have jQuery.

```
RowEntry = function(element) {
  this.$el = element; // pass the row as a jQuery element
  this._init();
}

RowEntry.prototype._init = function() {
  var _this = this; // for accessing this in anonymous functions

  this.$el.find(".selling-price").on("keyup", function(event) {
    // do the math here or call functions that do
    // you can access 'this' here as '_this'
  });

  // you can setup other event listeners too if you want
}
```

So in your partial, you'll have something like:

```
<script>
  var row = $(".row-entry") // you'll need to introduce something to reference the row
  new RowEntry(row);
</script>
```

Comment: can i do this without jquery like i want to loop the javascript for doing this dynamically

Comment: Of course you can. You'll probably end up with messy code. The whole idea is to get things modularised so that you can focus on specific details within those modules.